# What does double pointer mean and malloc of size of pointer date type

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

```
int **matrix, i, j;
matrix = malloc(5 * sizeof(int*));
*matrix = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
```

I just don't understand the concept of double pointers and how this translates to a two-dimensional array ( that is if it's true )
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 6):

What is being created here is not technically a 2D array but an array of pointers, each of which would contain the starting address of an array.  This can then be indexed as if it were a "real" 2D array.

This line creates an array of 5 pointers to `int`:

```
matrix = malloc(5 * sizeof(int*));
```

The next line creates a single array 20 `int`:

```
*matrix = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
```

This however is incomplete in terms of a 2D array because only one row was allocated.  You need to loop through every element that `matrix` points to in order to create each row:

```
int **matrix, i;

matrix = malloc(5 * sizeof(int*));
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    matrix[i] = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
}
```

When you're done using this dynamic 2D array, you'll need to free the memory in the reverse order:

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    free(matrix[i]);
}
free(matrix);
```

This differs from a real 2D array in a few ways.  First, in a true 2D array all elements are contiguous in memory, where in this case the array of pointers and each row array are not.

The other difference is when being passed to a function you can't pass it the same way you'd pass a real 2D array.

For a simple 1D array, whether allocated at compile time or dynamically:

```
int a1[5];
int *a2 = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
```

Both can be passed to a function like this:

```
void f(int *a);
```

But in the case of a 2D array:

```
int a[5][20];
```

It would need to be passed to a function like this:

```
void f(int a[5][20]);
```

Or equivalently:

```
void f(int (*a)[20]);
```

Whereas a dynamic 2D array needs to be passed to a function like this:

```
void f(int **a);
```

Answer (score 6):

Some pictures might help.

Let's start with `matrix`, which is a pointer to pointer to `int`:

```
  int **
+--------+
| matrix |---???
+--------+
```

After the first call to `malloc`, you have the following:

```
  int **        int *
+--------+    +-----------+
| matrix |--->| matrix[0] |
+--------+    +-----------+
              | matrix[1] |
              +-----------+
              | matrix[2] |
              +-----------+
              | matrix[3] |
              +-----------+
              | matrix[4] |
              +-----------+
```

You've dynamically allocated space for 5 `int *` objects, and `matrix` points to the first one.  After the second call to `malloc`, you have this (the expression `*matrix` is equivalent to `matrix[0]` - more on that below):

```
  int **        int *            int
+--------+    +-----------+    +---------------+
| matrix |--->| matrix[0] |--->| matrix[0][0]  | 
+--------+    +-----------+    +---------------+
              | matrix[1] |    | matrix[0][1]  |
              +-----------+    +---------------+
              | matrix[2] |    | matrix[0][2]  |
              +-----------+    +---------------+
              | matrix[3] |           ...
              +-----------+    +---------------+
              | matrix[4] |    | matrix[0][19] |
              +-----------+    +---------------+
```

You've dynamically allocated space for 20 `int` objects, and `matrix[0]` points to the first one.

So, in short - each `matrix[i][j]` is an `int`. Each `matrix[i]` points to `matrix[i][0]`, so each `matrix[i]` must be a pointer to `int`, or `int *`.  `matrix` points `matrix[0]`, meaning `matrix` must be a pointer to `int *`, or `int **`.

Remember that the array subscript expression `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)` - given an address `a`, offset `i` *elements* (not bytes!) from that address and deference the result.  Thus, `*matrix` is equivalent to `*(matrix + 0)`, which is equivalent to `matrix[0]`.

Now, what you have here is *not* a true 2D array - you have a sequence of pointers, each of which may point to the first of a sequence of `int` objects (or to nothing at all).  The "rows" of the array will (most likely) not be adjacent in memory.  In a true 2D array, all array elements will be contiguous.  Given

```
int matrix[5][20];
```

elements will look like this:

```
+---------------+
| matrix[0][0]  |
+---------------+
| matrix[0][1]  |
+---------------+
      ...
+---------------+
| matrix[0][19] |
+---------------+
| matrix[1][0]  |
+---------------+
| matrix[1][1]  |
+---------------+
       ...
+---------------+
| matrix[4][19] |
+---------------+
```

**EDIT**

Some other key differences between a pointer-to-pointer and a 2D array.  First, assume the following definitions:

```
int **ptr;
int matrix[ROWS][COLS];
```

1. The expression `ptr` has type `int **`.  The expression `matrix` will "decay" from type `int [ROWS][COLS]` to type `int (*)[COLS]` (pointer to `COLS`-element array of `int`);
2. `sizeof ptr` gives the size of the pointer itself (4, 8, or some other number of bytes).  `sizeof matrix` gives the size of the entire array in bytes (`ROW * COLS * sizeof (int)`).
3. The expressions `&matrix`, `matrix`, `&matrix[0]`, and `&matrix[0][0]` will all yield the same *value* (the address of the first element of the array), although the types of the expressions will be different - `int (*)[ROWS][COLS]`, `int (*)[COLS]`, `int (*)[COLS]`, and `int *`, respectively.  The expressions `&ptr`, `ptr`, `&ptr[0]`, and `&ptr[0][0]` will not all yield the same values - `&ptr` and `&ptr[0][0]` will be different values than `ptr` and `&ptr[0]`, and the types of the expressions will be `int ***`, `int **`, `int **`, and `int *`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the following:

```
int **matrix, i, j;
matrix = malloc(5 * sizeof(int*));
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    matrix[i] = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
```

Here you first allocate an array of pointers to rows. Then you allocate memory for each row.